# Problems with using hmset in Predis

Tags: php, redis, predis

I have a problem with using `$predis->hmset()`. What parameters i need use? 
I try many variants, but without success.

```
$this->client()->hmset( $this->name, array( 1 => 3 ))

$this->client()->hmset( $this->name, array( 1, 3 ))
```

Comment: https://github.com/nrk/predis/blob/v0.8/FAQ.md#how-predis-implements-abstraction-of-redis-commands ?

Answer (score 11):

From [the predis examples](https://github.com/nrk/predis/blob/v0.8/examples/MultiBulkReplyIterators.php):

```
// Prepare an hash with some fields and their respective values.
$client->hmset('metavars', array('foo' => 'bar', 'hoge' => 'piyo', 'lol' => 'wut'));
```

Perhaps, make sure you use strings and not integers ...

Comment: Error was in connection to redis. Thx for answers :)